# Babelify breaks down

Tags: babeljs

I have create a Gulpfile.js :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('browserify', function(){
  return browserify('./app/app.js')
        .transform(babelify, { stage: 1})
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
});
```

i have app.js in the app folder and need to apply browserify task on it, the app.js contains this react class

```
var React = require('react');
var PropTypes = React.PropTypes;

var App = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div />
    );
  }

});

module.exports = App;
```

when i run this

> gulp browserify

it gives me this error :

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
ReferenceError: [BABEL] E:\learn\react\RMD\public\assets\app\app.js: Using removed Babel 5 option: base.stage - Check ou
t the corresponding stage-x presets http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#presets while parsing file: E:\learn\react\RMD\publi
c\assets\app\app.js
    at Logger.error
```

Comment: Have you added below to your `.babelrc`? 
{
  "presets": ["stage-0"]
}

Answer (score 3):

> Using removed Babel 5 option: base.stage

```js
.transform(babelify, { stage: 1})
                       ^^^^^
```